# My PHP code is wrong syntax. I can't find error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I just learn code php. i can't find error PHP code.I observe Php code can error by without alphabet like I enter for make line 57. Php can error line 57 In spite of without alphabet.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\pmdb\ch9\example9-2\index.php on line 56

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KDme.png)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" description="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" description="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Example 9-2</title>
      <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="../../js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
      <script src="../../js/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
          td {
                font-size: 0.87rem;
          }
          caption {
                caption-side: top;
                text-align: center;
          }
      </style>
</head>
<body class="p-4">
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:3307', 'root', '', 'pmdb_ch9');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM people';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
      echo $mysqli->error;
      goto end_page;
} else if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
      echo 'ไม่มีข้อมูลในตาราง people';
      goto end_page;
} 

echo '<table class="table table-sm table-striped">
          <caption>ข้อมูลจากตาราง people</caption>';

//อ่านข้อมูลที่ละแถวจาก result set ในแบบออบเจ็กต์
while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
      echo <<<HTML
      <tr>
            <td>$data->id</td>
            <td>$data->name</td>
            <td>$data->address</td>
            <td>$data->email</td>
      </tr>
      HTML;
}
echo '</table>';

end_page:
$mysqli->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I thankyou a lot. if you can help me.

Comment: The [Go To](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/goto.png) expressions mean that the table is never going to be displayed as both conditions of the `IF` statement direct the output beyond...

Answer (score 1):

The heredoc closing identifiers should not be indented.
According to [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> Warning It is very important to note that the line with the closing
> identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;).
> That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and
> there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.
> It's also important to realize that the first character before the
> closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating
> system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including macOS. The closing
> delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

Try to use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" description="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" description="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Example 9-2</title>
      <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="../../js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
      <script src="../../js/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
          td {
                font-size: 0.87rem;
          }
          caption {
                caption-side: top;
                text-align: center;
          }
      </style>
</head>
<body class="p-4">
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:3307', 'root', '', 'pmdb_ch9');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM people';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
      echo $mysqli->error;
      goto end_page;
} else if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
      echo 'ไม่มีข้อมูลในตาราง people';
      goto end_page;
} 

echo '<table class="table table-sm table-striped">
          <caption>ข้อมูลจากตาราง people</caption>';

//อ่านข้อมูลที่ละแถวจาก result set ในแบบออบเจ็กต์
while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
      echo <<<HTML
      <tr>
            <td>$data->id</td>
            <td>$data->name</td>
            <td>$data->address</td>
            <td>$data->email</td>
      </tr>
HTML;
}
echo '</table>';

end_page:
$mysqli->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot you is the best of php programing.